# How to create layout like Android Newsstand app?

Tags: android, listview, header, android-viewpager

I want to create a layout like this screen of Play Newsstand app?

[image]

What I want is when I swipe left and right, the fragments and indicators change while the header is not. When I scroll up, the header will disappear like header of a listview. Can any one suggest me how to achieve it? Thanks so much.

Comment: R U trying to put web site like look and feel on android device ???